# VBA to store file name in a cell

Tags: vba, directory, filenames

I am trying to target the file name/directory to a cell in excel which I have chosen by a ms file dialog box. So far I have managed to do it for one file but if i multi-select the files it doesn't store all the file names sequentially instead it just does only the first file.

```
 With fd
          .AllowMultiSelect = True
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "All files", "*.*", 1
.Filters.Add "SIG Files", "*.SIG"
.Filters.Add "FLG Files", "*.FLG"
.Filters.Add "TCS Files", "*.TCS"
.Filters.Add "ROU Files", "*.ROU"
.Filters.Add "PTS Files", "*.PTS"
.Filters.Add "QST Files", "*.QST"
.FilterIndex = 1
.Title = "Select SSI Identity File"
.InitialFileName = ""
  If .Show = -1 Then
  ReDim selectedPaths(.SelectedItems.Count)


        For I = 0 To .SelectedItems.Count - 1
        selectedPaths(I) = .SelectedItems(I + 1)


                 lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 54).End(xlUp).Row

       Z = lRow + 1

           **Range("BA5").Offset(I, 0).Value = selectedPaths(I)**
```

I wanted to fill range BA5 with file names/directories sequentially as my fdbox allows multi select option.

Appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be something like that:

```
For I = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
    Range("BA" & 4 + I).Value = fd.SelectedItems(I)
Next I
```

If you want to cut off the directory, use instrrev in the second line:

```
Range("BA" & 4 + I).Value = Right(fd.SelectedItems(I), Len(fd.SelectedItems(I)) - InStrRev(fd.SelectedItems(I), "\"))
```

EDIT (to comment below)
If you want to add new filename in the first free cell in BA column, it it even simpler:

```
For I = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
    Range("BA" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = fd.SelectedItems(I)
Next I
```

Comment: Hi It works great but if i try to add through the file dialog box second time it just overwrites the one already in there! Any solution for that.......... Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Hi , Thanks for helping me put. I was trying input the above code in a select case and seems it doesn't wok. Here is my code

Comment: `Select Case Filename = Right(fd.SelectedItems(I), Len(fd.SelectedItems(I)) - InStrRev(fd.SelectedItems(I), "\"))



Case Right$(selectedPaths(I), 3) = "QST" Or Filename = QST.ID

 
`